# bind raw socket to specific address

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am doing raw socket programming in C. I am creating my own ethernet, ip and tcp headers. Then I add data to the packet and send it. Then I need to wait for response from the other program.

I have one computer. So using **lo** as my interface. I have something like

```
CreateSocket
BindSocketToInterface
Sendto
recvfrom
```

Now it is receiving it's own data which is undesirable. So I am thinking to bind socket to specific address. 
Can I do it?
Also How to do it??

Can select solve this problem ??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Like if you want interface then as follows

```
char *opt;
opt = "eth0";
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, opt, 4);
```

But if you want port address then

You cannot bind a raw socket to a specific port because "port" is a concept in TCP and UDP, not IP. Look at the header diagrams for those three protocols and it should become obvious: you are working at a lower level, where the concept of port is not known.

Comment: port is ok. but can't bind it to address also, in my case ?? Also can select call be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setsockopt` to bind it to a specific device.

```
struct ifreq *ifr = <populate some values>;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)ifr, sizeof(struct ifreq))
```

Try the above code and it should work. populate the `ifreq` correctly for the required network device.

Comment: what device can it be?? would it be interface, like eth0 or lo?

Comment: yes, it can be any network interface like `eth0 or lo`

Comment: That is not solving the problem. I already did this. Because it's same for both sender and receiver. I want IP address so that I send by 127.0.0.1 and could receive from 127.0.0.2 and hence could restrict on its basis. or can select serve the purpose??